# (PHP) header(Location: ...)

Tags: php, location

Is there a way I can change the header instead of adding on?
For example

Creating a user

create_user.php (a form to action.php) -> action.php (switch case which will call another function) -> user_controller.php

So from user_controller.php, upon successful creation, i used the header method to bring the user to another location, view_user.php.

So now the url header is like

```
http://localhost/dct/action.php/web/view_user.php?&success=[SUCCESS]%20User%20is%20created!
```

but i want it to be

```
http://localhost/dct/web/view_user.php?&success=[SUCCESS]%20User%20is%20created!
```

without the action.php. How do i go about achieving that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use URL rewriting - this depends on your setup. You can either do it at the web-server level, or application-level.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

- save your "base_url" website (`http://localhost/dct/`) in parameter and call `header('Location: ' . $baseUrl . '/veiw_user.php?...)`
- Simply add a `/` before your URL (example: `header('Location: /view_user.php?...')`, and it will redirect from the root of your website, but in your case, it will redirect to `http://localhost/view_user.php?...`.

The first way is better for your case, but you have to update the parameter when you publish your website in production environment.